# How to create new list of an object attribute from a list of those objects?

Tags: r, r-s4

I am working with `git2r` and want to create some basic statistics about the project's activity.

`git2r` returns all commits as a list of S4 objects. Below I'm showing the structure of the first object:

```
> library(git2r)
> repo <- repository('/Users/swain/Dropbox/projects/from-github/brakeman')
> last3 <- commits(repo, n=3)
> str(last3)
List of 3
 $ :Formal class 'git_commit' [package "git2r"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ sha      : chr "f7746c21846d895bd90632df5a2366381ced77d9"
  .. ..@ author   :Formal class 'git_signature' [package "git2r"] with 3 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name : chr "Justin"
  .. .. .. ..@ email: chr "presidentbeef@users.noreply.github.com"
  .. .. .. ..@ when :Formal class 'git_time' [package "git2r"] with 2 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ time  : num 1.5e+09
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ offset: num -420
  .. ..@ committer:Formal class 'git_signature' [package "git2r"] with 3 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name : chr "GitHub"
  .. .. .. ..@ email: chr "noreply@github.com"
  .. .. .. ..@ when :Formal class 'git_time' [package "git2r"] with 2 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ time  : num 1.5e+09
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ offset: num -420
  .. ..@ summary  : chr "Merge pull request #1056 from presidentbeef/hash_access_interpolation_performance_improvements"
  .. ..@ message  : chr "Merge pull request #1056 from presidentbeef/hash_access_interpolation_performance_improvements\n\nHash access i"| __truncated__
  .. ..@ repo     :Formal class 'git_repository' [package "git2r"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. ..@ path: chr "/Users/swain/Dropbox/projects/from-github/brakeman"
```

I have searched high and low for a way to extract one slot from all objects into a list. For example, for all the S4 objects in the list `last3` I want to pull `author` into this new list. Note that there's nesting of objects here, so I may want to make a list from something on an object that's in a slot of the top object.

Ultimately I want to start creating plots and summaries of the various fields. For example, a bar chart of commits by day of the week; box plots of the message length by committer; things like that. Is converting slots to lists or vectors the wrong way to go about it? (edit: s/histogram/bar chart/, doh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org/) solution to what you're trying to achieve. Jenny Bryan has a nice set of introductory documents on how to use purrr (and other packages) for this sort of task: https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/.

```
library(git2r)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

repo <- repository("/git-repos/brakeman/")

# Get relevant bits out of the list
analysis_df <-
    repo %>%
        commits(n = 50) %>%
        map_df(
            ~ data.frame(
                name    = .@author@name,
                date    = .@author@when@time %>% as.POSIXct(origin="1970-01-01"),
                message = .@message
            )
        )

# A histogram of commits by day of the week;
analysis_df %>%
    mutate(weekday = weekdays(date)) %>%
    group_by(weekday) %>%
    tally() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = n)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")

# box plots of the message length by committer
analysis_df %>%
    mutate(message_length = nchar(message)) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(mean_message_length = mean(message_length)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = mean_message_length)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Wow, more than I could have wished for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

How about

`lapply(last3,function(x) data.frame(author = x@author@name, email = x@author@email))`

Comment: Thanks! This will be very useful.